# Trace width at high frequency

Tags: pcb, rf, microwave

What trace width and height is required for a 1 A current at 3 GHz? Can the cross section of the trace be smaller than in case of DC or low frequency currents because of the skin effect? Will the trace heat up less due to the hf AC current?

Comment: yes resistance will rise significantly

Comment: Skin effects mean that the trace has to be wider/fatter. It will heat up more at higher frequency.

Comment: Neglecting other parameters, the skin depth for 3 GHz is ~1.3 um. If your PCB manufacturer is able to make the copper thickness lesser than or equal to 1.3 um then the skin effect *may not* be a problem.

Comment: You've also got the potential of dielectric losses due to the pcb. Specialist pcb material like Teflon are used to lessen this effect at microwave frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

At 3GHz you need to be concerned about more than skin effects with dielectric loss tangent. GETEK ML200M is a cost effect choice but it depends on your total loss specs and path length.

Skin Effect for 3GHz means you can use 0.5 Oz copper means the depth is only 13% which is not bad, but surface roughness means you have far greater losses than an ideal smooth surface.

The average engineer might assume the skin effect means it conducts only the top-surface which you can chemically flash coat  with gold. **But just the opposite is true.**  **The current flows at the dielectric conductor interface.** Next,  surface roughness comes in several process grade levels of Electro-Deposited (ED) copper foil.

RTF Reverse Treated Foil for 0.5 Oz looks like good-one-side plywood, rough and rougher ;)    under a microscope but may be cost-effective.

VLP Very Low Profile  0.5 oz looks more like smooth wood veneer but as expected, costs more.

The oxide treatment is also a critical process used on some PCBs for better adhesion.  **A few microns would result in poor loss, much worse than 1.2um surface roughness for a skin depth 1.2 um.**  As you can imagine, this magnifies the surface length and path loss greatly like walking thru mountains than going over hills.

Surface roughness also affects the dielectric constant more with thinner substrates and creates a parameter called the **process Dk** which thus affects your controlled impedance and Return Loss.

- For high current 3GHz you would need something like  a Trace Width to Height ratio of Gnd plane > 2 , < 3 depending on Dk for 50 Ohms.  ( 2:1 is typical but increases as effective Dk decreases )

> Will it heat up?

Maybe not significantly,  but then there are more critical factors like path loss, return loss, and other signal  parameters.

( I assume you wouldn't consider  a skinny track  for 1A )